# Scale Label text in line with Label size

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

Looking for a way to resize a `Labels` text in line with the change in size of the `Label`.  (ie. should a label increase in size by `50%`, then the text should also increase in size by approx `50%`).

There is plenty of articles around which adjust the text to fit fully within the size of a `Label`, which isn't suitable for what I want.
I already have a working version of this.

Somehow I need to be able to reference the previous size of a `Label` once the resize is complete in order to determine the ratio to use in order to resize the text.

Comment: You'll most likely have to implement this yourself in the [`SizeChanged`  event handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.sizechanged?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) of the label

Comment: If the label height or width only increases by 50% and you would increase the text by 50%, than it wouldn't match anymore. How should the text behave in these cases? All that makes sense to me, would be to find out the greatest font size, so the text matches the box (maybe with some padding). Anything else would fail in some scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you could simply do is to get the actual size of the label with the contents inside then use a factor to obtain a new size.

You can get the render size of the label using;

```
System.Drawing.Size TextRenderer.MeasureText (string text, System.Drawing.Font font);
```

After obtaining the render size of the label you can re-set the label.width and label.height by multiplying the returned size with a factor (ex: Size *0.5) would give you the half of the required size.

You can use the same method in SizeChanged event handler of Label to determine if the MeasuredSize;

- Less than current label size: increase font size until it reaches ~=labelsize
- Larger than current label size: decrease font size until ~=labelsize or

  Equal to current label size: do nothing?

I hope I could give you some insight on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

An example using [Graphics.ScaleTransform()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.scaletransform?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Drawing.Graphics.ScaleTransform);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2), used to prepend a transformation matrix to the Graphics operations that follow.

Note that this transformation is applicable as long as the Graphics can draw a Font in a given size. If the Font is too small or too large, the rendering will not work as expected.
The minimum Font size should be `8.5 ~ 9` points and no more than `72`.
 Outside this range, the result are unpredictable. (e.g., the Text may simply disappear).
Thus, a Control minimum/maximum size should be set at design time and not be scaled beyond these measures.

The `Label.TextAlign` property is set to `ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft` here.
Also: `.AutoSize = false;` `.Text = "Some text that needs to fit";`

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Text;

private void label1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Label label = sender as Label;
    e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
    float TextWidth = e.Graphics.MeasureString(label.Text, label.Font, label.Size, StringFormat.GenericTypographic).Width;
    float scale = (label.ClientSize.Width - label.Padding.Left) / TextWidth;
    e.Graphics.Clear(label.BackColor);
    e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(scale, scale);

    using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(label.ForeColor))
        e.Graphics.DrawString(label.Text, label.Font, brush,  
                              new RectangleF(PointF.Empty, label1.ClientSize), 
                              StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
}
```

The visual result:

[image: Text ScaleTransform]